# Insert data from a table into another with auto-generated ID

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `ASSET` that has an attribute `ASSET_ID`, which is the unique ID, generated through a `sequence`. I can insert a line with

```
insert into ASSET (id, name)
values (default, "john")
```

All my "names" are stored in an another table called staging, so I would to do something like the below, where I give the default parameter to the first field, and the content of my staging table to name.

```
insert into ASSET (id, name)
   values (
      default, 
      select * from STAGING)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just leave `id` out of the statement and use `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into asset (name)
    select name
    from staging;
```

Comment: This gives me 00947 - not enough values. This is circumvented however when explicitly specifying the 'default' value for my ID

Comment: @notverygood . . . There are enough values in this query, so I don't see how that could be the error.  Your query must be different.